# Load SQL Trigger from file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am trying to load custom database triggers from sql file in resource folder.

In my test class I added this anotation `@Sql("classpath:custom_script.sql")`

In this file I have triggers for PostgreSQL database. When I execute this scripts from PgAdmin's query tool they work fine, but when I loading it from before tests in Spring Boot application, I got following error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [custom_script.sql]: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_TRIGGER_PROC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $CUSTOM_TRG$ DECLARE FOO_V INTEGER; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 64 in SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_TRIGGER_PROC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $CUSTOM_TRG$ DECLARE FOO_V INTEGER. Expected terminating $$

In custom_script.sql I have three related triggers like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_TRIGGER_PROC()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $CUSTOM_TRG$
DECLARE FOO_V INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(F.ID)
  INTO FOO_V
  FROM FOO_TABLE F;

  IF FOO_V > 0
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'CUSTOM EXCEPTION ERROR MESSAGE FOR ID ', NEW.ID
    USING ERRCODE = 'restrict_violation';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$CUSTOM_TRG$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER CUSTOM_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON FOO_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_TRIGGER_PROC();
```

I expected that error will be because of delimiter or multi-line problem so I add these properties into properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
spring.datasource.separator=^;
```

and also edit my script as you can see in code below but it didn't help. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Edited script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_TRIGGER_PROC()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $CUSTOM_TRG$
DECLARE FOO_V INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(F.ID)
  INTO FOO_V
  FROM FOO_TABLE F;

  IF FOO_V > 0
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'CUSTOM EXCEPTION ERROR MESSAGE FOR ID ', NEW.ID
    USING ERRCODE = 'restrict_violation';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$CUSTOM_TRG$
LANGUAGE plpgsql^;

CREATE TRIGGER CUSTOM_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON FOO_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_TRIGGER_PROC()^;
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use single quotes around the function definition instead of $CUSTOM_TRG$ as used here; in similar cases the $$ dollar-quoting should again be ditched in favor of simple single quotes.  However, the single-quoting of the entire definition requires escaping quotes within the function definition, as mentioned in the Postgresql documentation:

> It is often helpful to use dollar quoting (see Section 4.1.2.4) to write the function definition string, rather than the normal single quote syntax. Without dollar quoting, any single quotes or backslashes in the function definition must be escaped by doubling them.

So in your example, you would need to double the single quotes in your function definition, occurring in the logic where FOO_V > 0.